# Calculating a huge least common multiple of various numbers and printing it modulo a prime

Tags: c++, algorithm, numbers

I was in a programming competition and I needed to calculate the order of a permutation on a million number. Of course the order of a permutation is just the least common multiple of the cycle length.

Therefore the problem boils down to this: given some integers that add up to one million I need to calculate their least common multiple. Of course the least common multiple could be huge. The problem asks me to print the answer mod 10^9+7 which is a prime. How would I be able to do this?

I am not sure how because reducing the result each time I calculate it will make me unable to calculate the least common multiple after.

Just to be clear I know how to calculate the least common multiple since it is just the product of the numbers divided by the greatest common factor, and calculating the greatest common factor is simple with the euclidean algotihm.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: In your last paragraph you correctly said how to calculate the lcm. The result modulo some numer is easy too. So, is your question how to avoid int overflow with 32bit int´s, or what else do you want?

Comment: Yes, that was my problem, luckily it got solved. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, it is good. the problem I was having is that when I calculated the lcm it could easily go over 100 digits. but if I reduced the result I would lose all the divisibiliy information about the numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate the prime factorization of the LCM, then multiply all those primes together mod 10^9+7:

```
long modulus = 1000000007
long product = 1;
for (long prime : primes) {
    product = (product * prime) % modulus;
}
```

Comment: So should I build a prime sieve up to one million?

Comment: @Gamamal: That's probably one of the steps I'd take.

Comment: It does not work: with just number `4`, it would produce `2`.  You need to compute the product of all prime factors each to the largest power seen in a decomposition.

Comment: I think the variable prime represents the largest power of the prime that divides an element of the array, not the prime itself.

Comment: @Gamamal: The given code is assuming `primes` stores primes with multiplicity, mostly because I didn't think of calling the variables `prime_power` and `prime_powers`.

Comment: yes yes, I understood the idea. I was just explaining to chqrlie. It is good.